# How to assign different values to two different table without writing almost same code for other table?

Tags: java, android-tablelayout

I want to create two tables which have different headers in first row. both tables have 4 columns in header row. How can i create two table with different header values without writing this same code twice?

```
public void addHeaders(TableLayout t) {

    /* Create a TableRow dynamically */
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setBackgroundColor(GRAY);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


    /* Creating a TextView to add to the row */
    TextView addressTV = new TextView(this);
    addressTV.setText("Address");
    addressTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    addressTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    addressTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    addressTV.setPadding(0, 7, 0, 7);
    addressTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.7f));
    tr.addView(addressTV);  // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /* Creating a TextView to add to the row */
    TextView typeTV = new TextView(this);
    typeTV.setText("Type");
    typeTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    typeTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    typeTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    typeTV.setPadding(0, 7, 0, 7);
    typeTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    tr.addView(typeTV);  // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /* Creating another textview */
    TextView amountTV = new TextView(this);
    amountTV.setText("Amount");
    amountTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    amountTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    amountTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    amountTV.setPadding(0, 7, 0, 7);
    amountTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.2f));
    tr.addView(amountTV); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /* Creating another textview */
    TextView dateTV = new TextView(this);
    dateTV.setText("Date");
    dateTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    dateTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    dateTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    dateTV.setPadding(0, 7, 0, 7);
    dateTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.5f));
    tr.addView(dateTV); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the header names as an input.  Then you can reuse the code to create your table objects while dynamically adjusting the header text fields.

e.g. Here is simple example, assuming always 4 columns...

```
public void callingFunction() {
    TableLayout tl1 = // something;
    TableLayout tl2 = // something else;

    addHeaders(tl1, "Address", "Type", "Amount", "Date");
    addHeaders(tl2, "new", "strings", "for", "table");
}

public TableRow addHeaders(TableLayout tl, String ... names) {
 if (names.length != 4) throw new Exception("Unexpected number of table header names");

/* Create a TableRow dynamically */
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setBackgroundColor(GRAY);
tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


/* Creating a TextView to add to the row */
TextView addressTV = new TextView(this);
addressTV.setText(names[0]);
addressTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
addressTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
addressTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
addressTV.setPadding(0, 7, 0, 7);
addressTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.7f));
tr.addView(addressTV);  // Adding textView to tablerow.

/* Creating a TextView to add to the row */
TextView typeTV = new TextView(this);
typeTV.setText(names[1]);
typeTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
typeTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
typeTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
typeTV.setPadding(0, 7, 0, 7);
typeTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
tr.addView(typeTV);  // Adding textView to tablerow.

/* Creating another textview */
TextView amountTV = new TextView(this);
amountTV.setText(names[2]);
amountTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
amountTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
amountTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
amountTV.setPadding(0, 7, 0, 7);
amountTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.2f));
tr.addView(amountTV); // Adding textView to tablerow.

/* Creating another textview */
TextView dateTV = new TextView(this);
dateTV.setText(names[3]);
dateTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
dateTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
dateTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
dateTV.setPadding(0, 7, 0, 7);
dateTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.5f));
tr.addView(dateTV); // Adding textView to tablerow.

// Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I tried something like this before posting question but i was not passing input parameters correctly.